# How to get Test-cluster output in object format?

Tags: powershell, failover, failovercluster

The command [`Test-Cluster`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/test-cluster) is producing an output as a xml and htm file.

```
$v = test-cluster -Node w16-sqlcA,w16-sqlcB -Include "Storage" -Force -Disk $csv -Verbose
```

Seems like only way to get the detailed result is by parsing the xml. I have to get the Name of the activity and result of it as if it is shown in the below htm file.

[image]

Is there any built-in way of getting it? (or is already a parser is written for  test-cluster result?. I searched and found none). Please help.

Comment: Is there any way for me to replicate this without having my own cluster?

Comment: @JacobColvin if hyperV is enabled and virtual disk are created ,this might be possible . But if simply running cluster cmdlets how it will behave i am yet to check

Comment: Hm unfortunately I don't have the resources to check. If you had some way to allow us to replicate, or if there was some way to serialize the output, I bet you'd get an answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a test, an xml file with the results gets generated in C:\Windows\Cluster\Reports

You can use this function to check how many tests have a specific result status

```bsh
function Get-ClusterValidationResultCount
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('Failed','Warning','Success','Not Applicable', 'Canceled')]
        [String]
        $Status
    )

    $validationFile = (Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\Cluster\Reports -Filter "Validation Data*.xml" | Select -First 1).FullName
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty("$validationFile")) {
        throw "No validation xml found"
    }

    $results = Select-Xml -Path "$validationFile" -XPath "//ResultDescription" | Where-Object { $_.Node.Value."#cdata-section" -eq $Status }
    return $results.Count
}

Get-ClusterValidationResultCount -Status Failed
```